# Making sure all CORE Perl Modules are Installed on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, perl, package

I am pretty careful to use CORE Perl modules  -- the modules that  are documented in http://perldoc.perl.org -- whenever I can. For example, I use `Time::Piece` rather than `DateTime` or `IO::Uncompress` rather than `Archive::Zip`.

We have thousands of Chef managed servers, and we can guarantee a particular version of Perl is installed, but it becomes a nightmare to guarantee that particular CPAN modules are also installed.

Imagine my surprise when a script failed on a new server because `Data::Dumper` wasn't installed. That module had been part of the CORE modules since the very earliest versions of Perl 5.

I found out that Oracle Linux Release 7 (which is modeled after RHEL 7) divided up the standard Perl packages, so the base Perl no longer installs all of the CORE modules.

What RPM packages do I need to install on Oracle Linux Release 7 (and probably RHEL 7) to guarantee all CORE Perl modules are installed?

Comment: On RHEL 7 you have to install the [perl and perl-core packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Developer_Guide/lib.details.html#libraries.perl) (the perl package should be installed by default). CPAN isn't even included in the perl package! And yet Red Hat pretends that this is no big deal (it's a ["documented feature"](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1110564)). ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since RHEL is mainly for servers, it could be that the missing core models might have something to do with possible security issues. However, I can't see how that would be an issue with `Data::Dumper`. I was looking for some package to install, but there were over 100 Perl RPM packages. `perl-core` was lost in the middle. Change between RHEL 6 and 7 threw us.

Comment: The logic behind the split is explained here: https://lwn.net/Articles/348090/

Comment: So it was someone deciding what constituted the minimal Perl experience. I guess I can see why `Data::Dumper` didn't make the cut. I think it would have been better calling them `perl-minimum` and `perl-complete` and completely eliminate `perl`. RHEL is mainly a server install and you rather install more than have services that break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On RHEL 7, you have to install [these packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Developer_Guide/lib.details.html#libraries.perl):

- `perl`: includes the Perl interpreter, perldoc, and a subset of the core modules
- `perl-core`: the rest of the core modules

I'm guessing Oracle Linux 7 is the same because there's a perl-core-5.16.3-286.el7.x86_64.rpm in the [public yum repo](http://public-yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/index.html).

---

If you want to be doubly sure, you can check what `perl-core` provides by installing `yum-utils` and running:

```
repoquery --requires perl-core
```

(`perl-core` is just a meta package that lists a bunch of other `perl-*` packages as dependencies)